# get specific value from json file by Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, promise

Im using the $.get to get JSON file content which is working fine,currently I want to filter and get the item with Id 4 (the last one) ,how should I do that ?
in the Jquery doc I didn't find some hint to it...
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

this is the code:

```
 $.get('tweets.json');
```

this is the JSON file content

```
[
  {
   "id": 1,
   "tweet": "OMG, worst day ever, my BF @BobbyBoo dumped me",
   "usersMentioned": [
     {
      "id": 10,
      "username": "BobbyBoo"
     }
    ]
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "tweet": "OMG, best day ever, my BF came back to me"
  },
  {
   "id": 3,
   "tweet": "OMG, worst day ever, just don't ask"
  },
  {
   "id": 4,
   "tweet": "@BobbyBoo OMG...just OMG!",
   "usersMentioned": [
     {
      "id": 10,
      "username": "BobbyBoo"
     }
    ]
  }
]
```

**update**

Currenlty when I try the following I dont get anthing in the then(function (tweets) ,tweets is emtpy 
the value entry4 is filled with the correct value...

```
  $.get('profile.json').then(function (profile) {

    $('#profile-pre').html(JSON.stringify(profile));

     $.get('tweets.json', null, null, 'json')
        .then(function (response) {
           var entry4 =  response.filter(function (tweet) {
               return tweet.id === 4;
            })[0];
             return entry4 ;
        })



}).then(function (tweets) {

    $('#tweets-pre').html(JSON.stringify(tweets));

    var myFriend = $.get('friend.json');

    return myFriend
}).then(function (friend) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```
$.get('tweets.json',null,null,'json')
  .then(function(response){
    var iAmNumberFour = response.filter(function(tweet){
      return tweet.id === 4;
    })[0];
  });
```

Added the type since if you don't pass the right headers, jQuery won't parse the JSON for you.

---

```
$.get('profile.json').then(function(profile) {

  $('#profile-pre').html(JSON.stringify(profile));

  return $.get('tweets.json', null, null, 'json')
    .then(function(response) {
      var entry4 = response.filter(function(tweet) {
        return tweet.id === 4;
      })[0];
      return entry4;
    })

}).then(function(entry4) {

  $('#tweets-pre').html(JSON.stringify(tweets));

  var myFriend = $.get('friend.json');

  return myFriend
})
```

Comment: @A.Wolff That also works :D But I find `$.get` easier to remember.

Comment: I find `$.getJSON()` more readable, anyway +1 for this correct answer :=)

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer-thanks,voted up ,please see my update since I already use promise I dont get anything in then(function (tweets) {,any idea

Comment: Are you sure `response` contains the correct content?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum-sure ,I was able to get the value with ID 4 from the json in iAmNumberFour value but not sure how to pass it to the next promise...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum-any idea?

Comment: Yes, use return values `return iAmNumberFour`

Comment: @AlBundy One magic trick `then` does is that when you return a Promise inside it, the next chained `then` gets whatever it resolved. If you do `return $.get(...)` in the inner get which just then'ed `return entry4` then you'll get `entry4` in the chained `then` of your first AJAX call. If you didn't do this, then the chained `then` gets `profile` instead.